# conflict in stepcarousel and tooltip in jQuery

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I am trying to use step carousel and tooltip on the images of the step carousel, but for some weird reason they don't seem to work together ? Any ideas how I can get them working ?
I am using jQuery 1.7 and I know that step carousel is supporting jQuery 1.4. Is there any specific order of the jQuery to be included ?
Please let me know.

P.S: I do get an error
        $("#search_term").autocomplete is not a function
               autoFill:false
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only load one version of jQuery in the page and make sure that it is loaded before all plugins. The second version is overwriting the first and the plugins that were registered within the first version. jQuery is typically backwards compatible with plugins written when lower versions were available